# Tried to use state variable inside another state variable, but it didn't work as expected it to, Why ? (in ReactJS using function component)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component

I was trying to use a state variables value inside another state variable, but when the other sub state variable was updated outside, its updated value didn't get reflected in parent state variable, why did this happened? can I not use state variable inside another state variable or is there any specific way to use it?
Can anyone explain this please?

```
const [noOfPersonstForRoom, setNoOfPersonsForRoom] = useState([2]);

const [ageOfPerson1ForRoom, setAgeOfPerson1ForRoom] = useState([0]);
const [ageOfPerson2ForRoom, setAgeOfPerson2ForRoom] = useState([0]);

    const [rooms, setRooms] = useState([
    {
        roomNo: 1,
        noOfPersons: noOfPersonsForRoom[0], 
                    ageOfPerson1: ageOfPerson1ForRoom[0],
                    ageOfPerson2: ageOfPerson2ForRoom[0]
        

        
    },
]);
```

This is code of what I tried, with some changes.

To change sub state variable, I used following function, and it was called on onChange() of an input field:

```
const changeNoOfPersonsForRoom = (e, index) => {
        let newNoOfPersonsForRoom = e.target.value;
        setNoOfPersonsForRoom([
            ...noOfPersonsForRoom.slice(0, index),
            e.target.value,
            ...noOfPersonsForRoom.slice(index + 1),
        ]);
```

Comment: Tangential: any time there's a meaningful numeric suffix on a variable you probably want an array *(or similar ordered collection)*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you add how you update your state(s)?

But in general, states are not bound or connected to each other.
If you change one state, it won't update any other state.

```
const [rooms, setRooms] = useState([
    {
        roomNo: 1,
        noOfPersons: noOfPersonsForRoom[0], 
        ageOfPerson1: ageOfPerson1ForRoom[0],
        ageOfPerson2: ageOfPerson2ForRoom[0]
    },
```

Given your example, you just set the initial state of `rooms` with the values of your previous states. Nothing more. If you need to update several states, you have to update each of them separately.

Comment: so when noOfPersonsForRoom will be updated outside, because states are not connected to each other, 
the value of noOfPersonsForRoom inside rooms state will be as it was initially given, 
and will not change, and it will just become a static value
and noOfPersons value will not be changed by any done outside by setNoOfPersonsForRoom
untill it is changed by setRooms.

Is that Right ?
Did I understand it correctly ?

Comment: and is there no other way that I can update sub state varible inside the state varible ?

Comment: Exactly, you update your `noOfPersonsForRoom` state with `setNoOfPersonsForRoom`. This won't change any other state. You'll need to update the other states as well, you can do that in your `changeNoOfPersonsForRoom` as well.

Just a piece of advice: 
You might want to rethink your state structure since it seems complex and you are holding some of your states redundantly. (If I got your idea correctly). You could accomplish your problem with only the `room` state, and update this state in your `changeNoOfPersonsForRoom`. (But that's unrelated to your questions)